# Problema con cargar el servidor con Webpacks

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Tengo un problema, al usar npm start no me carga el servidor en el puerto que deberia aparecer. O sea, entro a mi pagina localhost:8080 y me sale "error" y cannot get error en la pagina.

Solo aparece `[webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:`  y asi vacio, no me dice en que puerto se esta ejecutando.

Solo instale npm -install -webpack-cli webpack-dev-server y npm install typescript ts-loader --save-dev.
Luego un npm init -y para crear mi archivo ts.json y mi webpack-config.js

Al realizar esto me sale:

```
> modulos@1.0.0 start
> webpack-dev-server --mode development

asset modulos.js 265 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 27.4 KiB 12 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 175 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 69.8 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.18 KiB
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.94 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.8 KiB
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 7.91 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/named-references.js 73 KiB [built] [code generated]
    + 2 modules
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./*.ts 1.66 KiB
  ./modulos.ts 1.38 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./persona.ts 284 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.90.3 compiled successfully in 2663 ms
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at: **ACA NO SALE NADA como mencione anteriormente**
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4):  **aca sale lo que debe**
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv6): **aca sale lo que debe**
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from **aca sale lo que debe** directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Gracefully shutting down. To force exit, press ^C again. Please wait...
¿Desea terminar el trabajo por lotes (S/N)? N
```

Cabe aclarar que estoy aprendiendo de modulos de TypeScript, soy basico en esto, es para empezar con Angular

Comment: haz un ng version y agrega las versiones a la pregunta para ver si es por ahí que no funciona

Comment: Hola Alan, ¿que version de `webpack` y `nodejs` estas usando?

Comment: No tengo instalado angular aun como para ver su version. De node tengo la ultima version LTS de la pagina y webpack ahora me fijo

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.2"

Comment: @AlanStone, ¿estas seguro que la versión de `nodejs` es [`>= 18.12.0`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/v5.0.2/package.json#L24)? Proba ejecutar `webpack-dev-server` con el flag `--stats verbose`

Comment: La ultima que sale en node.js es la 20.11.1 LTS

Comment: El usar eso me dice: El término 'webpack-dev-server' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o 
programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es 
correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.